# How do I clear files marked with a "!" in 'svn status'?

Tags: svn

I added files to my SVN but didn't commit them (so that they showed up with an "A" flag in 'svn status'). But then I decided to rename them before committing. I meant to add them and commit, but "svn status" shows the files with the old names marked with a "!" and I can't get rid of this. How do I do it? I even tried "svn delete *" / "svn remove *" in the directory but doing an 'svn status' after this still shows the files (which are not on my local hard drive) with the old names, marked with a '!'.

Answer (score 3):

When using wildcards (`*`) the “remove” command removes all files that match this wildcard – that is, all files in the directory.

*But there are none* – you’ve already deleted them. So no files get removed as far as SVN is concerned.

You need to remove those files explicitly. If there are many of them, you can use `grep` and `awk` to retrieve the relevant files from the status output:

```
svn st | grep `^!` | awk '{ print $2 }' | xargs svn rm
```

(untested, use carefully!)

Comment: Wow, that's annoying. I'll be sure not to do that again... thanks for the help. Seems like there should be an easier way to do this! Btw it was unclear what meant by "the command" -- I used svn remove <filename> and it worked.

Comment: @svnn00b Well, I said “ *when using wildcards* … the command …”. When you type `svn rm <filename>` then of course that works. No wildcards used here.

Comment: Yes, I took your advice and it worked, like I said above. I was just pointing out that you could improve your answer by specifying which command you mean by "the command". Thx again for the help.